# How to make boolean as method result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, boolean

I create a method which is supposed to send me a boolean.
But within it there is a loop who send also boolean.
Sometimes the loop send true sometimes false and I would like my method to send true as soon there is one true.

```
def update_with_former_email?(update_email)
  self.versions.each do |version|
    next if version.object.nil?
    version.object.include?(update_email)
  end
 end
```

For the moment when I call my method like:

```
person.update_with_former_email?("orsay@gmail.com")
```

it sends me the whole object `self.versions`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each` returns the object it was called upon, i.e. `self`. To return an actual boolean value derived from `include?`, you can use `return`:

```
def update_with_former_email?(update_email)
  self.versions.each do |version|
    next if version.object.nil?
    return true if version.object.include?(update_email)
  end

  return false
end
```

***or better*** use `any?` instead of `each`:

```
def update_with_former_email?(update_email)
  self.versions.any? do |version|
     version.object.present? && version.object.include?(update_email)
  end
end
```